# Unable to locate element (without Id) in webpage using selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to access/locate the element shown in the image and have tried various methods. xpath, classname, css but keep getting the error that the element cannot be found. Can you help please ?

[image: Locating "Choose image"]

**Attempt1**

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(".btn.btn-default").send_keys(os.getcwd() + "InputFiles/Error.png")
```

*Error:*

[image]

**Attemp2:**

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='upload-btn__wrapper']").send_keys(os.getcwd() + "InputFiles/Error.png")
```

*Error:*
[image]

Comment: Could you post your code, error message, and stack trace?

Comment: .btn.btn-default should work

Comment: try classname `.btn.btn-default` and NOT `btn btn-default`(space should not be there)

Comment: any exception you see ?

Comment: HI Gerard and Nikhil, thanks for your response, But i tried your suggestion and it didnt help. Please see attemp1 in the question above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath is supposed to work.

```
"//div[@class='upload-btn__wrapper']/button"
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Santosh, just trying your suggestion, will let you know how it goes. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help you. Let me know if you need further assistance.

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='upload-btn__wrapper']")

Comment: HI Greedy, thanks for responding, but I still got an error when i tried your  suggestion. See attempt 2 above .

Comment: It seems you have got multiple reference of the class upload-btn__wrapper. Can you please confirm

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use below Xpath as it will rely on your Text, so any changes in text of the button will result a failure of the test, which makes perfect sense.

```
//button[normalize-space(text())='Choose image']
```

Also use explicit wait before performing any operations with that element.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space(text())='Choose image']")));
WebElement chooseImageButton=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space(text())='Choose image']"));
chooseImageButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution as well :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'margin-bottom')]")).findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'upload-btn__wrapper')]")).click();
```

**Explanation** : I am navigating from the parent div which is "**margin-bottom**" div class and reaching out to the child div which we want to locate, which is "**upload-btn__wrapper**".

Let me know, if this works out.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on it with css selector also. Hope this will work for you.
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-default")).click();`